# infinite union and intersection of disjoint sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Find the sets 
$$
\bigcup_{N=1}^\infty\left(\bigcap_{n=N}^\infty A_n\right) \text{ and } \bigcap_{N=1}^\infty\left(\bigcup_{n=N}^\infty A_n\right)
$$
if

**(1)** $A_1,A_2,\dots$ are pairwise disjoint 
**(2)** if $A_n=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
                  B \text{ if } n \text{ is odd}\\
C \text{ if } n \text{ is even}
                \end{array}
              \right.$
For **(1)** my argument is that $\bigcup_{N=1}^\infty\left(\bigcap_{n=N}^\infty A_n\right)=\emptyset$ (as I first take the intersection of disjoint sets which is empty) and $\bigcap_{N=1}^\infty\left(\bigcup_{n=N}^\infty A_n\right)=\infty$ (as I first take the union of a infinitely large set, and that the intersection of infinitely large set is infinite) **Am I correct?** 
For **(2)** $\bigcup_{N=1}^\infty\left(\bigcap_{N=1}^\infty A_n\right)=\bigcup_{N=1}^\infty\left(B_1\cap C_2 \cap B_3 \cap C_4\cap \ldots \right)$ and $\bigcap_{N=1}^\infty\left(\bigcup_{n=N}^\infty A_n\right)=\bigcap_{N=1}^\infty\left(B_1\cup C_2 \cup B_3 \cap C_4\cup \ldots \right)$, but I havve really no idea how to proceed from here.

Comment: In your own answer $(1)$ you mixed up some indices I think (in the second part).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, $\cap_{N=1}^{\infty}  ( \cup_{n=N}^{\infty} A_n) = \infty$ makes no sense as a set can be of infinite cardinality but not be equal to infinity.

Now regarding your task: I assume that there is some set $A$ given such that $A_n \subseteq A$ for all $n$ (if not, let $A = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$). I think it would help you to understand that

$$\bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty} \left( \bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty} A_n \right) = \left\lbrace a \in A ~ | ~ \text{There exists } n_0 \text{ such that } a \in A_n \text{ for all } n \geq n_0 \right\rbrace$$
and
$$\bigcap_{N=1}^{\infty} \left( \bigcup_{n=N}^{\infty} A_n \right) = \left\lbrace a \in A ~| ~ a \in A_n \text{ for infinitely many } n \right\rbrace $$
no matter what $A_n$ actually is.

This way it is easier to see that for **(1)** we have
$$\bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty} \left( \bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty} A_n \right) = \emptyset = \bigcap_{N=1}^{\infty} \left( \bigcup_{n=N}^{\infty} A_n \right) $$
and for **(2)** we have
$$\bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty} \left( \bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty} A_n \right) = B \cap C ~, ~ \bigcap_{N=1}^{\infty} \left( \bigcup_{n=N}^{\infty} A_n \right) = B \cup C.$$

Answer (score 1):

The following characterization can be helpful:

$$a\in\bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty}A_{n}\iff\left\{ n\in\mathbb{N}\mid a\notin A_{n}\right\} \text{ is a finite set}$$

$$a\in\bigcap_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{n=N}^{\infty}A_{n}\iff\left\{ n\in\mathbb{N}\mid a\in A_{n}\right\} \text{ is not a finite set}$$

(1) Set $\left\{ n\in\mathbb{N}\mid a\notin A_{n}\right\} $ is not
finite and $a\in A_{n}$ cannot be true for more than one index $n$. So
both sets are empty.

(2) Set $\left\{ n\in\mathbb{N}\mid a\notin A_{n}\right\} $ is finite
if and only if $a\in B\cap C$ and set $\left\{ n\in\mathbb{N}\mid a\in A_{n}\right\} $
is infinite if and only if $a\in B\cup C$.